# Mapfish Print Linux Problem

Tags: linux, mapfish

I'm using Mapfish Print Tool in Windows and everyhing works correctly. But when I print the same template on Linux server, Mapfish Print doesn't print all elements when printing on formats like png or jpg. It does work only with pdf.

Do you have any ideas, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have ImageMagick installed?

http://www.mapfish.org/doc/print/installation.html#with-image-output-line

> At the moment to have robust image (png, gif, etc...) output options the image magick command line tool must be used. The tool is cross platform and available on linux, windows and mac osx. Before installing mapfish print first install both:
>
> ImageMagick (specifically ensure that the convert tool has been installed)
> Ghostscript
> Once ImageMagick is installed (and Ghostscript) then the spring configuration needs to be updated so that org.mapfish.print.output.NativeProcessOutputFactory object will be used as an option for creating output files.